# Multiple instances of the same (foreign) word

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

Consider the following snippet:

> The Spanish word **lágrima** comes from Latin *lacrima* which also has a
>   descendant in English. When you cry, your eyes get their tears from
>   special glands known as **lacrimal sac**. These glands are named after
>   *lacrima*. *Lacrima* also happens to have descendants in other Romance
>   languages.

If you notice, there are three instances of the Latin word in the snippet. If I am following a style where I italicize foreign language words, is it necessary for me to maintain consistency by italicizing every single occurrence of the same word just because it's foreign? Or should I just italicize the first instance of *lacrima* here?

Comment: Related: *[Italicizing foreign language words in an English Essay](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175669)*.

Comment: This is off topic, and should be migrated to [Writers.SE].

Comment: But btw, in a linguistics paper when talking about a word as a lexical object you would always italicise it, even if the word is an English one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a certain style guides opinion, then you italicize just the first occurrence:

> **"7.49 Italics for unfamiliar foreign words and phrases**
>
> Italics are used for isolated words and phrases in a foreign language if they are likely to be unfamiliar to readers... If a foreign word becomes familiar through repeated use throughout a work, it need be italicized only on its first occurrence. If it appears only rarely, however, italics may be retained.

--*Chicago Manual of Style Online,* 16th editon

Comment: Oh, interesting

Comment: Indeed, MLA says exactly the same. ("Foreign words or special terms are also introduced by placing them in italics [the first time only]." I wonder, then, why it never seems to be done this way.

Answer (score 2):

Italicize in all instances.

For example see *mise en abyme* [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=6zy_wNN0St8C&pg=PA49&dq=mise%20en%20abyme&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N35rVMH9EMbnygPyrYAI&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=mise%20en%20abyme&f=false).

...Also "unheimlich" [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Jf70-7NZlRwC&pg=PA199&dq=unheimlich&hl=en&sa=X&ei=X_xrVLfAIaqaygP0nYKABA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=unheimlich&f=false).

EDIT: I want to hedge my original response by pointing out that both the MLA and Chicago style guides seem to disagree with me. Both argue that only the first instance should be italicized, unless there is a very long space of text between them. 
It's not clear that authors follow this rule, however.

Comment: I'm wondering if *mise en abyme* isn't being used as a technical term in that text. But, still, I'm not sure I'd italicize a technical term every single time.